# summation of numbers in a vector without loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, loops, sum

I have a vector with length `L`. I want to sum each `N` numbers without a loop in MATLAB for saving time in my simulation.

For example, if `L=10` and `N=2` for the matrix

```
A=[1,1,3,3,0,2,4,4,6,2]
```

the matrix `B` should be

```
B=[2,6,2,8,8]
```

where

```
B(1)=A(1)+A(2)=2
B(2)=A(3)+A(4)=6
```

Comment: reshape the initial vector into a `NxL/N` vector then sum column-wise then reshape back

Answer (score 3):

```
B = sum(reshape(A, 2, []));
```

If length of A could be odd number:

```
n = floor(numel(A)/2) * 2;
B = sum(reshape(A(1:n), 2, []));
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also be considering movsum.

```
C = movsum(A,2);
B = C(2:2:end);
```

I evaluated its performance to `B = sum(reshape(A, 2, []));` Movsum takes roughly 2x the time of reshaping. But it offers some flexibility and runs for non-even length vectors.

Comment: It seems movsum doesn't work in matlab 2014,I should try it in 2016.